# How to copy a folder into another in a Makefile?

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile that looks like this:

```
push:
    docker build -t dataengineering/dataloader .
    docker tag dataengineering/dataloader:latest 111111111.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dataengineering/dataloader:latest
    docker push 111111111.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dataengineering/dataloader:latest

deploy:
    @if [ ! "$(environment)" ]; then echo "environment must be defined"  && exit 1; fi
    @if [ ! "$(target)" ]; then echo "target must be defined"  && exit 1; fi
    kubectl delete deploy dataloader-$(target) -n dataengineering|| continue
    kubectl apply -f kube/$(environment)/deployment-$(target).yaml -n dataengineering
```

So the problem is that I am building a dockerfile that is going to copy folders but the folders aren't in the right place. I have a tree that looks like this:

```
├── dataloader
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── Makefile
...
│   ├── dataloader.py
│   ├── dates.py
│   ├── errors.py
│   └── tests
├── datastore
│   ├── datastore
    ...
```

and what I'm trying to do is copy all of the datastore folder into the dataloader folder but right now they are siblings. How do I do this?

Comment: 1. *Which* `datastore` folder? I see two. 2. Which makefile rule do you want to do the copying?

Comment: Make sends each line of a recipe to a POSIX shell (sh) to be invoked.  So whatever command you would type at the shell prompt to do this copying, you can put into your makefile recipe.

Comment: the top level datastore folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to copy the `datastore` directory *into* the `dataloader` directory, it's a simple `cp` command: `cp -r ../datastore/ ./` (considering you're executing this is the `dataloader` directory).